# Storing data in javascript for server side processing

Tags: javascript

The problem is simple. I have something like chessboard in HTML. The fields have coordinates, stored in ID attribute (ROW|COLUMN)
Clicking on a specific field makes it marked/unmarked. What is more, selected field's row and column are stored in a `<input type="hidden"/>` in the form of ROW|COLUMN,ROW|COLUMN,...

For every click I have to process the value of input hidden to check whether the field is already stored, add new field, remove existing and so on. It's a little awkward.
Are there any better ways? Or maybe it is the best way?:)

Comment: is it possible not to do it on every click. but only when you r about to send the data to server, and collect the data once??

Comment: Well...maybe I could add a class to a selected field. And before sending form to server check which fields have this class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to store the fields state in an input field. Better use the a global JavaScript array or manipulate the DOM and serialize it's state before sending it to the server.

Here is some sample code in a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U2D9Q/

The important part is where the className of the columns

```
$td.bind("click", function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

and how it's serialized when you click the button

```
var serialize_table = function() {
    var output = new Array();

    $("table tbody").children().each(function(y) {
        var row = new Array();

        $(this).children().each(function(x) {
            row[x] = $(this).get(0).className;
        });

        output[y] = row;
    });

    return output;
}
```

I used jQuery to keep the code clean. Feel free to use any JS Framework you like or write native JS.